# Exchanging variables between LUA directives in NGINX

Tags: nginx, lua

I am using HttpLuaModule for my NGINX server. I want to ask if it is possible to recognize variable in different directives of this module. For example

```
 init_by_lua ' local global_var = 5 ' ;
 some config ;
 set_by_lua ' print(global_var) ' ;
```

How is that possible with NGINX and LUA module ?

Comment: i think you are talking just about simple lua scripting, i want to know if there it is possible to use variables from one directive to another on nginx configuration

Comment: i tested it, it works by removing local from global_var declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `global_var` to be global, don't declare it as local.

From a quick look at NGINX's docs, `init_by_lua` and `set_by_lua` work on the same global Lua state and so you'll be able to make them talk if you use global variables. Local variables set in `init_by_lua` will be lost.

So, it should work if you just remove `local` in `init_by_lua`.